# Kotlin setOnClickListener for a ListView

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have the following code:

```
class BookListActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    var array = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.book_list)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.book_list_item, R.id.book_title, array)
        val listView : ListView = findViewById(R.id.book_list)
        listView.adapter = adapter    
    }
}
```

I need to add a click listener for each element on the listView.

I've tried the following but doesn't work:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener
{
    val intent = Intent(this, BookDetailActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Also I need to know what ListView element I've clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to handle all the parameters for [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Your listener should look like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> 
    val element = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position) // The item that was clicked
    val intent = Intent(this, BookDetailActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: I would rather do `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this solution for listview item click listener.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {parent,view, position, id ->
          // Get the selected item text from ListView
          val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as String

          val intent = Intent(this, BookDetailActivity::class.java)
          startActivity(intent)
    }
```