# how to change listView Item content in Kotlin in an effecient way?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to build a basic app which illustrate flash cards in arabic and english. I built a listview and I want know to imply on click listner (I used and modified this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128123/kotlin-setonclicklistener-for-a-listview)so when I click on an item it shows me the back of the card. I figured out a way to do it  but then i should refresh the whole list once again. Is there a better way, so I just change the item I clicked? Thank you

```
        //listItems is just the list of Strings
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems)
        listView.adapter = adapter
        
        //i don't know how to chant the content of the element or the list view element
        listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val element = adapter.getItem(position)  // The item that was clicked
           
            listItems.set(position, "translation")

            listView.adapter = adapter

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView, ListView is an old way to display list in Android:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

And if you want to set on click listener in efficient way, I wrote a blogpost where the click listener is set in this manner:

https://brona.blog/2020/05/interaction-with-recyclerview-using-kotlin-dsl/

Cheers!